# filter dictionary array by property that matches a different array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, core-data, dictionary, predicate

I have two arrays and I'm trying to filter the first (array1) with a matching property that exists in a second array (array2). The first array is a dictionary array with key 'name'. The second array is an array of objects with property 'name'. Is it possible to filter contents of 'array1' and display only those that have a matching 'name' found in 'array2'? 
I've tried:

```
   NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == @%",self.array2];
   NSArray *results = [array1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
   NSLog(@"The results array is %@", results);
```

Rather than '==' I've tried a mix of 'IN' and '@K' and 'self' but it either crashes or results are 0.

Answer (score 1):

This should work with `IN`:

```
NSArray *matchSet = [self.array2 valueForKey:@"name"];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN @%",matchSet];
```

Typed in Safari.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891

Answer (score 1):

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [[array2 valueForKey:@"name"] containsObject:[evaluatedObject objectForKey:@"name"]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how you could accomplish this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *arrayOne = @[@{@"name": @"Alvin"}, @{@"name": @"Brian"}, @{@"name": @"Charlie"}];

        BMPPerson *alvin = [[BMPPerson alloc] initWithName:@"Alvin"];
        BMPPerson *charlie = [[BMPPerson alloc] initWithName:@"Charlie"];

        NSArray *arrayTwo = @[alvin, charlie];

        NSArray *values = [arrayTwo valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSMutableArray *filteredValues = [NSMutableArray array];

        [arrayOne enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSString *name = [obj valueForKey:@"name"];
            if ([values containsObject:name]) {
                [filteredValues addObject:name];
            }
        }];

        NSLog(@"%@", filteredValues);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the example, `arrayOne` is an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects. Each object has a key of `name`.

The objects contained in `arrayTwo` are a basic NSObject subclass that has a `name` property.

To get the values of the name properties for all of the objects in `arrayTwo` we make use of the key-value coding method `-valueForKey:` which calls `-valueForKey:` on each object in the receiver and returns an array of the results.

We then create an `NSMutableArray` to hold the filtered results from `arrayOne`.

Next we enumerate the objects in `arrayOne` using the `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method. In this example, we know that the `obj` argument is an `NSDictionary` that has a key of `name`. Instead of casting to an `NSDictionary` and calling `-objectForKey:` we can simply call `-valueForKey:` and store the value in our local variable `name`. We then check to see if `name` is in the `values` array and if it is, add it to our `filteredValues`.